# "Invalid procedure call or argument" calling regedit in Shell in Word 2013/2016

Tags: vba, ms-word, legacy-code

I have an issue with some legacy template code for Word. In 2007 it works fine, but in 2013/2016 I get an error "invalid procedure call or argument" from a Shell call. I've updated the code to use LongPtr as Microsoft instructs, but I'm still getting the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```vb
Const SYNCHRONIZE = &H100000
Const INFINITE = &HFFFF
Const WAIT_OBJECT_0 = 0
Const WAIT_TIMEOUT = &H102

#If VBA7 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" _
(ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, _
ByVal dwProcessId As LongPtr) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32" _
(ByVal hHandle As LongPtr, ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" _
(ByVal hObject As LongPtr) As LongPtr
#Else
Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" _
(ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, _
ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32" _
(ByVal hHandle As Long, ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" _
(ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
#End If

Public Sub SynchShell(ShellParam As String)
    #If VBA7 Then
    Dim lngID As LongPtr
    Dim lngHandle As LongPtr
    Dim lngRet As LongPtr
    #Else
    Dim lngID As Long
    Dim lngHandle As Long
    Dim lngRet As Long
    #End If

    lngID = Shell(ShellParam, vbMinimizedFocus)

    If lngID <> 0 Then
        lngHandle = OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE, 0, lngID)

        If lngHandle <> 0 Then
            lngRet = WaitForSingleObject(lngHandle, INFINITE)
            CloseHandle (lngHandle)
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

The passed argument for ShellParam is (from the Watch so ignore initial and final quotes): "regedit /e "C:\path\to\registry.reg" "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Company""

Comment: On the same versions of Windows? Any idea why the code is using the Windows API instead of Word's built-in functionality to access the Registry?

Comment: What is Word's built-in functionality? Sorry, I'm brand new to VBA and this code was inherited. I was going to see if switching from Shell to WScript.Shell will make a difference, but if there is an existing way to export a registry key in word I'll try that asap

Comment: Look up `System.PrivateProfileString` in Word's language reference (help).